# Get Nested AD Group Membership Path in R

Tags: r, dataframe, igraph

I have AD Group membership in below format:
[image]

```r
# source data format code
df <- data.frame(
  Parent_Group = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'),
  Group = c('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'G1', 'G1', 'G2', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'G11', 'G11'),
  Member = c('M1', 'M2', 'M3', 'G1', 'M4', 'G2', 'M5', 'M11', 'M12', 'G11', 'M13', 'M14'),
  MbrType = c('User', 'User', 'User', 'Group', 'User', 'Group', 'User', 'User', 'User', 'Group', 'User', 'User')
)
```

The Parent Group can have both user or another AD Group nested within. There are also multiple levels of nesting present in the actual data.

I want to have another column "Membership Path" **(desired format below)** that could show the full path of Membership like the one below:

[image]

Please note, the levels of Nesting varies for each group.

Looking for some assistance on how to achieve this in R.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `igraph` to build up the paths

```
library(igraph)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(df[c("Group", "Member")])
df %>%
    mutate(
        Membership_Path = sapply(
            shortest_paths(g, unique(Parent_Group), Member)$vpath, \(p) paste0(names(p), collapse = ">")
        ),
        .by = Parent_Group
    )
```

and you will obtain

```
   Parent_Group Group Member MbrType Membership_Path
1             A     A     M1    User            A>M1
2             A     A     M2    User            A>M2
3             A     A     M3    User            A>M3
4             A     A     G1   Group            A>G1
5             A    G1     M4    User         A>G1>M4
6             A    G1     G2   Group         A>G1>G2
7             A    G2     M5    User      A>G1>G2>M5
8             B     B    M11    User           B>M11
9             B     B    M12    User           B>M12
10            B     B    G11   Group           B>G11
11            B   G11    M13    User       B>G11>M13
12            B   G11    M14    User       B>G11>M14
```

Comment: Thank you but when I run this on the actual data set, the Membership path turns out to be blank for certain paths. I forgot to mention that all the values in  every column are prefixed with domain names (Eg: "contoso\Enterprise-Admins"). Could that be the reason why not all paths are showing up?

Comment: @CT_369, yes, that could be the reason